# Ubuntu 16.04 is connected, but no internet

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I have a System76 Galago Pro running 16.04.3.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/jrgifford/12637174809ae55ce96560c600b3b1b5) is the output of the diagnostic script.

What happens is that I'll connect to an access point, it will "be connected" however all packets will drop after about 10 seconds. If I force a reconnect to the SSID then it works for another 10 seconds. I can reproduce this consistently.

Comment: This [forum page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=164279) talks about an issue with same driver of yours (iwlwifi). Could you check it?

Comment: @Redbob Unfortunately I'm not sure what part of it solved the issue for them. At first glance, restarting wpa_supplicant every time I connect seems to fix it but I still experience waves of packet loss.